# I can't use the font that I wanted, is there any replacement for the Geometria typeface?

Tags: fonts

I am writing a game application and I was planning to use the [Geometria](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/geometria?q%5Bterm%5D=geometria&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y) typeface for small bits of text in all-caps (such as RESTART, NEXT LEVEL and so on). It looked just perfect but then I realized that I had misread the license and I am not allowed to do this without paying a license fee.

Can someone suggest a free replacement that looks equally professional? I have tried other geometric sans-serif typefaces but none of them look quite as good.

This is Geometria:

[image: Geometria example]

Comment: The extra-light version of [Source Sans Pro](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro) might be a suitable free alternative. It does allow embedding. There is a three-way trade-off between licensed use, cost and beauty.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for answering my question. I actually tried Source Sans Pro earlier, it is good but not on pair with Geometria. So I guess you are right; YGWYPF. I am not a graphic designer but my untrained eye can see a huge difference in quality between expensive fonts and free alternatives.